# R shiny: Google Chrome unresponsive with shiny application

Tags: r, macos, google-chrome, shiny

I have been testing my R shiny app on `Google Chrome` since past one month and it worked fine until this morning. Whenever I am trying to deploy it - locally or using the shinyapps.io server - it is getting unresponsive after a few seconds and suggests that I either wait or kill the page. I deployed the same app locally as well as via shinyapps.io in `Safari` and it worked absolutely fine.

Here is the link to a subset of it which has a similar behavior - https://rathik.shinyapps.io/data_marislab/

**UPDATE:**
Here is a snippet of my code, I have highlighted the section that is most probably causing the problem - if someone can help me find an alternative to it:

```
# ui.R
tabItem(tabName = "clge",
              fluidRow(
                box(selectInput(inputId = "clgeselectInput1", label = "Select dataset", 
                                choices = c('Dataset1'='dataset1',
                                            'Dataset2'='dataset2')),
                    actionButton(inputId = "clgesubmit1", label = "Load dataset"), width = 4, background = "navy"),
                box(selectInput(inputId = "clgeselectInput2", label = "Select Gene", choices = "none"), width = 3, background = "navy"),
                box(checkboxInput(inputId = "clgecheckboxInput1", label = "Log", value = TRUE), width = 2, background = "navy"),
                box(selectInput(inputId = "clgeselectInput3", label = "Sort by", choices = c('Variable', 'Value')), width = 3, background = 'navy')
              ),
              fluidRow(column(5, actionButton(inputId = 'clgesubmit2', label = "Get Expression Plot"))), br(), br(),
              plotlyOutput(outputId = "clgeplot1", width = 800, height = 800)
      )

# server.R
# select dataset from clgeselectInput1, when clgesubmit1 is clicked, a second selectInput clgeselectInput2 is updated with the rownames of selected dataset 
observe({
        if(input$clgesubmit1 == 0){
          return()
        }
        # this could be the problem
        ##############################################
        dat <- as.character(input$clgeselectInput1)
        dat <- get(load(paste0('data/',dat,'.RData')))
        num <- rownames(dat)
        updateSelectInput(session = session, inputId = "clgeselectInput2", choices = num)
        ##############################################
        # when I replace the above snippet with the below, it works fine!
        updateSelectInput(session = session, inputId = "clgeselectInput2", choices = c('MYC','MYCN'))

      })

# after clgeselectInput2 is updated with rownames, you can select and click on clgesubmit2 to output expression plot for selected gene.
output$clgeplot1 <- renderPlotly({
    if(input$clgesubmit2 == 0){
      return()
    }
    isolate({
      dat <- as.character(input$clgeselectInput1)
      dat <- get(load(paste0('data/',dat,'.RData')))
      gene1 <- as.character(input$clgeselectInput2)
      logvalue <- input$clgecheckboxInput1
      sortby <- input$clgeselectInput3
      plotGeneBar(dat = dat, gene1 = gene1, log = logvalue, sortby)
    })
  })
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Also tried changing the observe event like this but its still not working:

```
# reactive function
  clge <- reactive({
    dat <- as.character(input$clgeselectInput1)
    dat <- get(load(paste0('data/',dat,'.RData')))
    num <- as.character(rownames(dat))
  })

  # output expression plot for selected gene
  observe({
    if(input$clgesubmit1 == 0){
      return()
    }
    isolate({
      updateSelectInput(session = session, inputId = "clgeselectInput2", choices = clge())
    })
  })
```

As suggested elsewhere, I tried clearing my chrome cache as well. What else can I try in such a case?

Thanks!

Comment: Working fine for me

Comment: Like deploying my application? So there is a tab called Visualization tools > Gene Expression. When you click on Select dataset > Load dataset, after a few seconds, the Select Gene dropdown should be automatically updated with a list of genes that are in the dataset. This is where chrome gets unresponsive after some time. However, this exact same thing is working on Safari for me.

Comment: Try identify what has changed between yesterday and today (for example, chrome version, any R packages that you have updated, any javascript library that you have updated).

Comment: I checked. Nothing has been updated.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem and post a small example here please

Comment: I don't think there is anything to reproduce here when I have linked my actual application in the question itself. The problem is not about my code but about my chrome getting unresponsive, because my code is working fine as stated. I just wanted to know if there is anything - other than clearing the cache - that can make my chrome responsive. Thanks!

Comment: I see the irrespective message when I run in IE also, its waiting on something... Check your `plotly` dependencies inside the `clgeplot1`

Comment: @KomalRathi, Also you seem to have a memory leak somewhere within your app once I click the `Load dataset` button. Have a look at the `Task manager` to see the Chrome memory usage. For me it jumped from 50Mb to 200 Mb within 30 seconds

Comment: Thanks but I don't know how to find out where the leak is occuring. Also, I don't get it why my app is working in Safari and not in Chrome or IE (haven't checked that but I believe you tested it)?

Comment: `dat <- get(load(paste0('data/',dat,'.RData')))` shouldnt be there!

Comment: I tried to put it in a reactive function and call it but it is still not working. See UPDATE 2.